# HTML Image on % basis?

Tags: javascript, php, html

I want to create an HTML page which has the following:

There are 10 slots for image and there are 3 images, any one of the three image has 50% chance so it will acquire 50% (5 slots) and the rest two will take the left over 5 slots.

Is there any way to do this in js/php?

Any help would be appreciated!

Comment: I've modified my answer to probably now meet your needs. BTW: SO is not meant as a coding service. It is a platform where people that got stuck somewhere can get a helping hand to be able to go on. So, please have a crtical look at my code, understand it, and learn from it ;-)

Comment: @hherger Yeah I know it already but sorry to ask for such :D I thought about it but couldn't get any logic to implement so posted here :D

Comment: Ok, so have a look at my answer.

Comment: @hherger Yes just tried and it works like flawlessly! Thanks for that! also there was a minor error which I edited, you forgot to close the src tag :P

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's a snippet in PHP that probably helps you find a solution.

```
<?php
    $images = array(
        array( 'title' => 'mytitle1', 'path' => 'path/to/image1.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
        array( 'title' => 'mytitle2', 'path' => 'path/to/image2.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
        array( 'title' => 'mytitle3', 'path' => 'path/to/image3.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    //  array( 'title' => 'mytitle4', 'path' => 'path/to/image4.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    //  array( 'title' => 'mytitle5', 'path' => 'path/to/image5.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    //  array( 'title' => 'mytitle6', 'path' => 'path/to/image6.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    //  array( 'title' => 'mytitle7', 'path' => 'path/to/image7.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    //  array( 'title' => 'mytitle8', 'path' => 'path/to/image8.png', 'slots' => 0 ),
    );

    // Calculate # of slots to use per image
    $nimages = count($images);                  // # of images
    $nslots  = 10;                              // # of slots
    $rimags = $nimages - 1;                     // # remaining images
    $images[0]['slots'] = floor($nslots * 0.5); // # slots 1st image
    $rslots = $nslots - $images[0]['slots'];    // # remaining slots
    $xslots  = floor($rslots / $rimags);        // slots / image
    $xtra    = ($rslots % $rimags);             // extra slots

    for ($xi=1; $xi<$nimages; $xi++) {
        $images[$xi]['slots'] = $xslots + (($xtra>0) ? 1 : 0);
        if ($xtra>0) $xtra--;
    }

    // Generate HTML code
    echo '<div id="image_panel">' . PHP_EOL;
    $nslot = 1;
    foreach ($images as $img) {
        if ($img['slots']<1) continue;
        for ($xi=0; $xi<$img['slots']; $xi++) {
           echo '  '.$nslot.': <img src="'.$img['path'].'"     title="'.$img['title'].'" alt="'.$img['title'].'" id="'.$xi.'" />' . PHP_EOL;
           $nslot++;
        }
    }
    echo '</div>' . PHP_EOL;
?>
```

Comment: Uhm I don't want the image size to be big/small but take a look here maybe this should explain, http://i.imgur.com/UXgOTIG.png

Comment: Obviously this does not answer your question. Do you really want to display the #1 priority in 50% of the slots (5 slots of 10), etc.?

Comment: Yeah I want something like that!